# google cloud platform app.yaml for codeigniter php73

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, app.yaml

I can't figure out how to setup **app.yaml** for codeigniter 3 with php 7.3 gcp. Every useful link is about php55.. thanks in advance.

```
runtime: php73 # Replace with php73 to use the PHP 7.3 runtime

handlers:
# Serve a directory as a static resource.
- url: /stylesheets
  static_dir: stylesheets


# Serve images as static resources.
- url: /(.+\.(gif|png|jpg))$
  static_files: \1
  upload: .+\.(gif|png|jpg)$

# Serve your app through a front controller at index.php or public/index.php.
- url: .*
  script: auto
```

This is what I got from gcp docs. It works but css and js are not working. Everything is in assets folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have matching handler rules for css and js files, they'll only match the `- url: .*` rule, which isn't suitable (`script` handlers are designed for php scripts only).

You need to add rules for them, above the `- url: .*` one, maybe something along these lines (adjust for your app's particular needs):

```
# Serve css and js files as static resources.
- url: /(.+\.(css|js))$
  static_files: assets/\1
  upload: assets/.+\.(css|js)$
```